# Result from my curl not read as string

Tags: c, string-comparison, c-strings

I am writing this code for POS machine

i set the return data from the web link to "bad" so that i can test if it is really working.
but when i compare the result with a String "bad" it always say that they are not equal.
buy when i print the result to screen it display both result as bad.

Please i need your help. 
code below

```
void checklogin(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
        long timeout = 30;
        char buffer[50000];
    //Initializing the CURL module
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl){
    //Tell libcurl the URL
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL, "http://website.org/login.php");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=su&password=ch");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, myfunc);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, buffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); //tell curl to output its progress

           res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

           CTOS_LCDTClearDisplay();

           char mai[30];
           char mai2[30];

           char *serverresponse = "bad";
           sprintf(mai2, "%s" , serverresponse);
           sprintf(mai, "%s" , buffer);

           if(mai2 == mai){
            CTOS_LCDTPrint("Invalid username");
            CTOS_KBDGet(&key); 
           }else{
               //loginname = buffer;
               //mainusername = username;
               CTOS_LCDTPrintXY(1, 1, "Login Success");
               CTOS_LCDTPrintXY(1, 2, "Welcome");
               CTOS_KBDGet(&key);
               }


    }
}
```

Comment: Google comparing strings in C.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison you do works in C++, however for C, you need to use [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) for comparing strings. The return value will be `0` if the two strings you provide as arguments contain the same content. Also keep in mind that you can use other `strcmp()` functions when you need, such as `stricmp()` when you want to make a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 0):

mai2 and mai are pointers to the first field of the char arrays. As these are different arrays, the addresses of them are of course different. You want to compare the content, therefore you do need to use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

```
#include <string.h>
strcmp("hello", "hello"); //0
```

result will be 0 if the two char arrays contain the same content.

```
if (strcmp(mai, mai2) == 0 ) {
    ...
}
```

-Hannes

Comment: That should probably be string.h - he seems to be using C, despite tagging this as C++.

Comment: You are right, Cubic. Thanks. Edited: string.h is standard C99, so it should compile with any standard compiler.